# SQL Server stored procedure - designate database to use

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am tasked with creating a stored procedure from a script I wrote which will update tables with data.

Since I run this script against a dev database and a live database, we have always manually changed the `USE DATABASE` in the script before running.

I am looking for a way to use `USE DATABASE` within a stored procedure.

Is this possible without having to create two stored procedures of the same script for each database (dev versus live)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean MS SQL Server.  You cannot use `USE ...` within a stored procedure, but you can directly reference a different database with fully qualified object notation.

`database.schema.objectname`

Example:

`dev_mydb.dbo.MyTable`

Do note though that if you need that database name to be variable then you will need to use dynamic SQL to set the dbname.

Comment: I realize I could add a condition in the stored and then duplicate all the scripting to fully qualify the table, but since the table names are the exactly the same in both databases, I was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: Nope, other than dynamic SQL that's what you're limited to

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I should have known it wouldn't be an easy thing to accomplish.